# How to delete the first digit of a given number?

Tags: c

How can I delete the first digit of a given number using a user defined function (Suppose the function is `DELTOP`) ?

For Ex.,

```
x=DELTOP(1748);
```

I want the value of `x` as `748`.

Would anybody tell me how to write this function easily ?

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: [For Sayantan only] Nije koro bhai, bhul hole amra achi. [Try it yourself first, we'll be there to help you out if any issues]. :-)

Comment: @Sayantan Dey What should the result be if the number consists only from one digit?

Comment: @SayantanDey: just because it's easy for me doesn't mean we should do it for you. Part of being a student is LEARNING. If you just get everyone else to do your homework for you, then you learn nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C++11 one-liner would be

```
int DELTOP(int x) {
    return std::stoi(std::to_string(x).substr(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can divide the number so often by ten, until your number is < 10.

```
1748/10 = 174
174/10 = 17
17/10 = 1
```

Now you know the iteration count 3 and you also have the 1 as multiplier and then you can use the following formula:
YourNumber - 1 (this 1 is the "multiplier") * 10^3 (the 3 is the "iteration count") = 748

Answer (score 0):

You teacher probably gave you this homework. My answer would be this:

```
std::string myString = "145";
int value = std::stoi(myString); //value = 145 
std::string answer = myString.substr(1, myString.size() - 2);
int answerInt = std::stoid(answer);
```

It's probably not what he would expect but I always liked to troll my teachers! It should work.